# Do I have to give kaffarah for breaking the fast when I had severe fatigue, depression and head pressure?

Tags: sawm

I was pretty young at the time (around 20 years old). I was suffering from Body Dysmorphic disorder (BDD) which is a type of OCD and this was causing me severe distress at the time. Medicine was not very effective. One day in Ramadan, I became severely depressed by noon as I was getting hungry. I was clinically depressed because of BDD anyway at that time. I broke the fast by eating to relieve myself and I did feel some relief after eating food. But I did not know about kaffarah of 60 days fasting at that time. Now after 13 years, I feel bad about having broken that one fast out of desperation. Do I have to make Kaffarah for that? Or am I excused because I was mentally suffering and eating only would have relieved it? But I definitely did not break the fast just because I was hungry and wanted to eat something. Scholars says that the only way you are excused to break the fast and not offer kaffarah is that if your hunger might lead to some fatal consequences which would not have happened in my case just because I was severely depressed. My conscience is very heavy because of this.
Note: I belong to the part of the world were Hanafi school of thought is followed.

Comment: We are not a fatwa site and do not give personalized verdicts. Kaffarah is due on breaking a fast with sexual intercourse, there is difference of opinion on whether you need to offer kaffarah for breaking a fast by merely eating. The cautionary approach would be to pay it, especially if you are healthy or financially able to do it.